# How to extract values using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have one string

```
var str = '';
str += 'category='+jv('category')+'&';

str += 'refresh_rate='+jv('refreshRate')+'&';

str += 'submit=Y';
```

now I want to take values from jv('category') and jv('refreshRate') in separate string in javascript (I want to extract values after "=" and before "&").

Thanks.

Comment: Question is unclear. What is `jv`, and where is the category and refreshRate value coming from?

Comment: jv is like this

function jv(divid){if(document.getElementById(divid))
return document.getElementById(divid).value;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri
URI Parser in the past and find it simple to use and it doesn't rely on any other libraries. Its also pretty lightweight.

The author has a demo page but doesn't really explain how to use it..
Its really simple, you just do something like this:

```
var url = "http://my-site.com:8081/index.html?query=go&page=2";
var parsed = parseUri(url);
```

From there you can get things like the host/protocol/port/etc..
When dealing with the querystring you do

```
var page = parsed.queryKey.page;
alert(page); //alerts 2
```

Click the parse button on the demo page to see all properties of the parsed URI object that you can access..

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser or any other URL parser for this sort of string.